# Date logic (looking for first matching row in the past 90 days)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2022

I have a table of "patient visits" where each row records a single patient-visit event. In simplified form, the table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyVisits (
    PatientID char(10) NOT NULL, --Alphanumeric Patient ID
    VisitID char(10) NOT NULL, --Alphanumeric Visit ID
    Clinic varchar(10) NOT NULL, --Name of clinic visited
    DateVisit date NOT NULL --Date of visit
    EarliestVisitComment varchar(100) NULL -- Free text field
)
```

Patients - who always have the same Alphanumeric ID - may have only ever visited once, or very infrequently, or regularly.

What I need to do is, for each row, see if the given patient (using the PatientID field) had any *prior* visit within the previous 90 days (i.e. DateVisit minus 90 days), and record the Clinic + ' ' + VisitID for that visit (as a single string) in the EarliestVisitComment field.

If the patient has had *multiple* visits in the 90-day look-back window, I only want to identify the first / earliest visit the patient had in that window.

(If there is only one visit, then EarliestVisitComment can be null or blank.)

I have got as far as using ROW_NUMBER to partition and rank the data, but it feels like I am a long way off correctly grabbing the value I need, espcially as I have no interest in sequential visits *more* than 90 days apart. I have tried working with LAG() and NTILE() but feel stuck. I am sure I can figure our a "row-by-agonising-row" approach but hopefully there is a better way. Is there a kind SQL guru out there who can help?

Comment: Isn't it better to have a view that calculates this column. With a table, you will have to recalculate this every time something changes

Comment: @siggemannen excellent point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could just use a subquery.

```sql
UPDATE v
SET EarliestVisitComment = earliest.EarliestVisitComment
FROM #MyVisits v
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) EarliestVisitComment = earliest.Clinic + ' ' + earliest.VisitID
    FROM #MyVisits earliest
    WHERE earliest.PatientID = v.PatientID
      AND earliest.DateVisit >= DATEADD(day, -90, v.DateVisit)
      AND earliest.VisitID <> v.VisitID -- do you need this? what happens if there is only visit?
    ORDER BY
      v.DateVisit
) earliest;
```

But if you want to include cases where the visits are *more* than 90 days apart, but there are intervening visits *less* than 90 days apart then it's more complicated.

Comment: thanks so much. It seems obvious in retrospect, I evidently had a big blind spot on how to handle this. I did make a couple of changes - added TOP 1 to the subquery so it only returns a single answer per row and tweaked the sort order.

Thanks so much for helping me out